# stressapps Unsupported CPU type: Unable to force cache flushes

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, configure, stress-testing, archlinux-arm

I am trying to cross compile [stressapptest](https://code.google.com/p/stressapptest/) for ARM and I am able to successfully cross compile. But I am seeing lot of warnings during compilation.

For example,

```
sattypes.h:231:2: warning: #warning "Unsupported CPU type." [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Unsupported CPU type."
  ^
In file included from sat.cc:46:0:
os.h:160:4: warning: #warning "Unsupported CPU type: Unable to \
     force cache flushes." [-Wcpp]
   #warning "Unsupported CPU type: Unable to force cache flushes."
    ^
os.h:194:6: warning: #warning "Unsupported CPU type: Unable to \
       force cache flushes." [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Unsupported CPU type: Unable to force cache flushes."
      ^
os.h:217:6: warning: #warning "Unsupported CPU type: Unable to \
       force cache flushes." [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Unsupported CPU type: Unable to force cache flushes."
      ^
os.h:243:4: warning: #warning "Unsupported CPU type: Unable to \
      force cache flushes." [-Wcpp]
   #warning "Unsupported CPU type: Unable to force cache flushes."
    ^
os.h:273:6: warning: #warning "Unsupported CPU type: your timer \
       may not function correctly" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Unsupported CPU type: your timer may not function correctly"
```

My configure:

`./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --with-static`

Do I need to pass any additional arguments to fix the unsupported CPU type? It would be great if someone shared their experience.

Comment: They all look to be resolved by defining `STRESSAPPTEST_CPU_ARMV7A` (triggered by configure --host=armv7a or something like that).  See http://stressapptest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/os.h

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. Even after settings these variables i am seeing the same issue.

Comment: You can modify the source/headers with your own `#warning my trace` and see if it is really defined.  You can look at the os.h and some warnings are still emitted for the armv7a CPU.  It is something the application author did.  Some features will not work with an armv7a.  Search for *STRESSAPPTEST_CPU* in the os.h to see all the conditionals.

Comment: Yes added few warnings to os.h where it is been calling during compilation validation. But the ones which i have defined aren't called at all. I need to check more closely into os.h and its definitions.